# Why is my border-radius value with two slashes not working?

Tags: css

This works:

```
border-radius: .6em/.9em 0 1em;
```

And this string becomes striken by Chrome Developer Tools:

```
border-radius: .6em/.9em 0 0 .6em/.9em;
```

I just need to set equal border-radius for left corners. Why doesn't it work?

This also doesn't work:

```
border-top-left-radius: 1em/2em;
```

Comment: Remove the slash

Comment: A slash is fine, but there can only be _one_ of them in `border-radus`

Comment: Well,so this is the parser problem. Hmm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec only allows one `/` like this: `border-radius: .6em 0 0 .6em / .9em 0 0 .9em`

```css
.round {
    background:red;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border-radius: .6em 0 0 .6em / .9em 0 0 .9em
}
```

```html
<div class="round"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [most general syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) of `border-radius` is

Tx Rx Bx Lx / Ty Ry By Ly

You can have between 1 and 4 values for the x-radii and either

- 0 values for the horizontal (x) radius, in which case there is no slash and the radii are circular, or
- 1-4 values for the vertical (y) radii.

You cannot have two slashes. I think you were assuming that the syntax was `Tx/Ty Rx/Ry Bx/By Lx/Ly` but unfortunately this is just not the case.

Also, the slash is [simply not allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-left-radius) at all in the specific CSS properties like `border-top-left-radius`. If you want one elliptical corner radius it has to be done through `border-radius` I believe.